# Cannot get the name of zip file created by jersy api

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, spring-restcontroller

I created jersey rest post api with spring boot to return a zip file with such a filename, with postman i can download the zip file but not with real filename and in the response headers i can't find Content-disposition key.

My code is:

```
    @Context
    lateinit var httpServletResponse: HttpServletResponse

    @POST
    @Path("/getRecord")
    @Produces("application/zip", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getRecord(@RequestBody recordIdentification: RecordIdentificationRequest) {
        val compositeRecord: CompositeRecord = service.getRecordFromRequest(recordIdentification)
        var tmpFile: File? = service.getRecordZip(compositeRecord)

        if (tmpFile != null) {
            Files.newInputStream(tmpFile.toPath()).transferTo(httpServletResponse.outputStream)

            httpServletResponse.status = HttpStatus.OK.value()
            httpServletResponse.contentType = "application/zip"
            val contentDisposition: ContentDisposition = ContentDisposition.attachment()
                    .filename(tmpFile.name)
                    .build()
            httpServletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString())
            httpServletResponse.outputStream.flush()
        }

    }
```

the response headers in postman are:
[image]

thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was resolved the problem like this:

```
httpServletResponse.status = HttpStatus.OK.value()
            httpServletResponse.contentType = "application/octet-stream"
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + tmpFile.name + "\"")
            Files.newInputStream(tmpFile.toPath()).transferTo(httpServletResponse.outputStream)
            httpServletResponse.outputStream.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working directly with Servlet Classes, you could rely on the [Jersey Multipart feature](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest31x/media.html#multipart) that Jersey offers. That should make your life easier.

The documentation describes two ways, one Jersey proprietary way for Jersey 2.x and 3.0, and one Jakarta REST 3.1 way, implemented by Jersey 3.1, depending on what Jersey you are on.